# explorer command doesn't work in pwsh / Windows Powershell after upgrade to Windows 11

Tags: windows, powershell

In situations where I need to quickly switch from Powershell to the Windows Explorer, I used to be able to launch Windows Explorer from whatever directory I happened to be in, like this:

```
PS > explorer .
```

(This is really just calling `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`.)

It worked fine until upgrading to Windows 11. Now it silently fails to do anything.

I've confirmed that, even while using the new Terminal app, the command still works in the Command Prompt. And in pwsh, the `explorer` alias is still pointing at `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`.

So why is it now broken in Powershell? And is there any work-around?

PS: I have confirmed that the following do not work either:

```
PS > & explorer .                  # Nothing
PS > C:\Windows\explorer.exe .     # Nada
PS > & C:\Windows\explorer.exe .   # Zilch
```

Comment: I don't know if it'll make a difference, but you can try `Invoke-Item .` or `Start-Process .`

Comment: Does it work without the `.` or when passing an absolute path? Try `explorer $PWD`

Comment: Sorry to say, none of these variations has any effect, with or without the current directory argument, either as `.` or `$PWD`. Weirdly, even running `explorer` with cmd from within powershell does nothing. But if I launch a Command Prompt session from within the Terminal App, it works as expected.

Comment: Try this: `$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $shell.Open($PWD.Path)` or `$shell.Explore($PWD.Path)`

Comment: `explorer .` still works in all my Windows 10 and 11 PCs

Comment: @phuclv, Hm... It is a corporate PC I'm using. I wonder if there isn't some kind of security process installed that's nixing the Powershell invocation for some reason. When I run `explorer .`, the cursor turns into the blue spinny icon for a second before reverting, with nothing having happened in the interim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a workaround, but as you confirmed it working, I'll turn it into an answer:

```sh
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$shell.Open( $PWD.ProviderPath ) 
# Also works:
# $shell.Explore( $PWD.ProviderPath )
```

Create an instance of the [`Shell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell) COM object and then call its methods `Open` or `Explore` to open the current directory, obtained from automatic variable [`$PWD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pwd), in Explorer.

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) points out, we have to use `$PWD.ProviderPath` as `$PWD.Path` may be based on a PowerShell-only drive, which external programs such as File Explorer don't know about.

You might also want to check the **type of the provider** to make sure you call the above code only for filesystem paths:

```sh
# As a demonstration, let $PWD point to a registry location
Set-Location HKCU:\Software

# The following if branch won't be entered
if( $PWD.Provider.Name -eq 'FileSystem' ) { ... }
```